# How to get the reference of "Mtb"?

Tags: c#, minitab

I have added the reference "minitab 18.0 Addin Interface" and how to get the  reference of "Mtb"？

I googled many times but I could only find the code like the 
"Mtb.Application MtbApp = new Mtb.Application();"

I didn't know the sentence of "using Mtb = ?"

[image]

I know this is a newbie question but I never found any information for this.

Any help may be appreciated.

PS:Is there any doc or guide for it?

=========================================update===========================
·

I have 
[image]

and have tried the

using MinitabAddinTLB;

or

using Mtb = MinitabAddinTLB;

but
[image]

Sorry,still

[image]

Comment: Did `Mtb.Application MtbApp = new Mtb.Application();` work?

Comment: It doesn't work@LarsTech

Comment: That's weird. Maybe you can ask them directly. (support ftw)

Comment: Yeap,I may try version 17 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another reference named "mtb 18.0 Type Library" behind,which is the correct one.

I get used to the "minitab" and didn't scroll down to "mtb"line......

I feel I am so silly and maybe I need a rest.

Thank you all.

I need to work again.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I don't know exactly if there is a difference between 17.0 and
>   18.0, but maybe this can help you.

[image: Add Minitab Addin Interface]

And then you can add a public class implementing the MinitabAddinTLB.IMinitabAddin interface.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using MinitabAddinTLB;

public class AddIn : IMinitabAddin
{
  internal static Mtb.Application mtbApp;

  public void OnConnect(Int32 iHwnd, Object pApp, ref Int32 iFlags) {/* */}
  /* */
}
```

Comment: There is another reference named "mtb 18.0 Type Library" behind,which is the correct one.